# How do I get Multiple Style Sheets to work on a single page?

Tags: css, layout, html

Here's the situation.

1. I made three style sheets for each of the three pages I am currently working on.  One that works in IE8/Safari/Opera/Firefox.  One that works in IE7 and one which if used alone works on IE6
2. I tested everything on www.xenocode.com/browsers and that sites' IE 6 and 7 emulators.

3  I used a variation of the article's suggestions for a way to make all the sheets work.  (In the  section:

http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/excludecss.shtml

The problem is that while it calls up the proper css for IE 8 and IE 7 online (It works just fine directly off my computer), it can't seem to call up the code for IE6 properly online causing the layout to be messed up in IE 6 (Or at least the emulator on xenocode.com.

Is there a better method?

(Can't show you the full page, due to my client being adamant about not showing it until the project is finished.)

Comment: You could try browsershots.org for page rendering, since they open the site in a real browser, not an emulator. Might help determining where the problem for IE 6 is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using browser conditional statements...

I would check that the emulator your using is able to interpret browser conditional statements. If unsure you could always disable all other stylesheets and link normally (using the link tag) to just the IE6 stylesheet and then test

Comment: Actually, I did that.  It works fine both on and offline for the IE6 emulator if i JUST have the ie6 css be linked up.

Comment: Are you putting you IE6 conditional statement below the other stylesheets? otherwise because of the cascading nature of CSS the other styles would overide anything you declared in the IE6 sheet, nullifying the effect

Answer (score 0):

You want to have [IE6 specific CSS](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)? Also, please consider using [Microsoft SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/superpreview/) to locally see how your design looks in various versions of IE6.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these css selection tags for the specific Browser version for IE.

```
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie60.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 5.5000]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie55.css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 5.5000]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie50.css" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: You can also check this Modular Css slide show http://www.barbarosalp.com/post/2009/02/26/Moduler-CSS.aspx

Comment: To target all non-IE (not just Firefox), use <![if !IE]>(non-IE stylesheet here)<![endif]>

Answer (score 0):

http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

I love this thing because it lets me define granularly all the changes I want for different browsers / operating systems.